# Determining when there are new versions in core data model

Tags: ios, database, core-data, model, version

Short question:

I want to run a certain code in my app only if my Core Data model has changed (new entities, new properties, etc).  How can I determine if the model has changed or not?

Just some pseudo-code:

```
    if (current_model_version != previous_model_version) {
    //do some code
    } else {
    // do some other code
    }
```

I'm guessing I might use versionHashes to do this, or isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:, but I'm not certain how.

Some editing for clarity: 'current' as in 'now' and 'previous' as in 'last time app was launched.'

Comment: Perhaps the [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html) guide helps.

Comment: Yeah, I was digging through it.  isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata: solved it for me, but I sort of needed an example of an implementation to understand exactly how it was used.

Comment: `isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:` won't tell you that there is a new version - it will only tell you that there an _incompatible_ version. If your new version can be migrated automatically then this will return `YES`. _I'm only 90% sure about this - you might have to experiment to prove me right/wrong!_

Comment: You're absolutely right.  The second part of this for me is to set up data migration.

The app I'm working on classifies songs on the device according to certain criteria and stores that classification data in core data.  The developer who worked on it previously would simply empty out the database and re-classify all the songs every time the app version changed, regardless whether the database changed or not.  I'm setting it up so I don't have to classify the data every time the app version changes, and migrating the data is the natural next step.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer seems to be **isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMedia:**.

I found some useful information here:

http://mipostel.com/index.php/home/70-core-data-migration-standard-migration-part-2

I set it up this way:

```
- (BOOL)modelChanged
{
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * sourceURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:sourceURL error:&error];
    BOOL isCompatible = [[self managedObjectModel] isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];

    return isCompatible;

}
```

'self' is my shared data store, not that it necessarily has to go there.

deanWombourne points out that what this really does is determine whether or not the data can be automatically migrated, so it's not exactly the solution to the problem I posed.  It does serve my needs in this case.

Comment: There's a typo in there - don't pass sourcePath as the configuration parameter to isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:  Also note that this will only return YES if the store matches the current object model, so you can't use this to determine of the store can be migrated.  You have to try the migration and check for an error.

Comment: This should be returning the logical inverse of isCompatible, right?  If it isn't compatible, that's because the model has changed, correct?

Comment: I have replaced isConfiguration:sourcePath with isConfiguration:nil to make code working. It seems like a typo

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Haven't worked with this code in a while.  Wouldn't have caught it.

Answer (score 2):

This is replacement code for `- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator` that you get if you tick the Core Data box when setting up a new project in XCode.

It attempts to open the existing sqlite file (using lightweight migration if necessary).  If that fails, it deletes and re-creates the store.

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't open the store. error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        [self deleteSqliteFilesForStore:self.storeURL];

        if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:self.storeURL options:options error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

            // or [NSException raise ...]
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Store deleted and recreated");

            // TEST DATA RE-INITIALIZATION CODE GOES HERE
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Existing Store opened successfully");
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (void)deleteSqliteFilesForStore:(NSURL *)storeURL
{
    NSURL *baseURL = [storeURL URLByDeletingPathExtension];

    // Delete the associated files as well as the sqlite file

    for (NSString *pathExtension in @[@"sqlite",@"sqlite-shm",@"sqlite-wal"])
    {
        NSURL *componentURL = [baseURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:pathExtension];

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[componentURL path]];
        if(fileExists)
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[componentURL path] error:nil];
        }
    }
}
```